# hibernate v/s stored procedure or functions performance

Tags: performance, hibernate, plsql

I am analyzing the options for database layer in my application. I found hibernate a very popular choice however few friends told that better to use stored procedures / function rather than going for hibernate. Hibernate has performance issues compared to these database objects. Is there any other option. My application may have very high volume of transactions so need to select a option which gives a better performance. Can someone put some light on this and help me choose the best option. I am using spring framework as core and richfaces for web layer.

Comment: Is it feasible for you to just write a few simple test applications using both approaches, to measure the performance yourself?

Comment: I thought but one of the element in performance is database size which I would be able to simulate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My application may have very high
>   volume of transactions so need to
>   select a option which gives a better
>   performance

Well, if performance is your only (or primary) benchmark, then its hard to beat Oracle packages on the db server.  However, your company should consider the strengths of its developers.  Is this a shop with mostly Java devs and 1 or 2 lonely Oracle devs and 1 DBA?  If so, don't develop your middleware system in Oracle packages, you'll probably have some XML service written in Java using Hibernate.  Won't be as fast under load, but will be easier to maintain and grow for YOUR company.

Note: I'm biased towards using Oracle technologies, but thats where my strengths are.

Comment: As last we decided to go for pure jdbc and procedure in place of hibernate. This decision was based on some comparison reports found on internet and the fact we are looking high performance rather then development comfort.  Thanks tbone.

Comment: sure thing!  Also, you're probably aware, but just be proactive and setup coding standards, naming conventions, code promotion procedures, unit testing requirements, logging/exception standards, etc. from the start.  This seems to be more commonly known/followed in java shops for whatever reason, but not as much so with a group of database devs.  Just lay the rules/framework early on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you have anything on that. We are using MS SQL server. I think these guidelines will be same for any DB. We have someone to manage the database scripts but still want to double sure things go ok from start.

Comment: Check out this link:  http://www.toadworld.com/ORACLE/StevenFeuersteinsPLSQLObsession/PLSQLStandards/tabid/580/Default.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty late, but I would like to add a few points of using hibernate vs using stored procedures.

From a performance perspective I believe that since writing a stored procedure means you are closer to the database, it would invariably result in a faster output if written efficiently. Consequently hibernate, since its working on the database cannot really be faster than the database. The freedom to optimize queries is something hibernate steals from you and while hibernate may come up with many optimal queries, there may still be some chances for better optimization.

Even pro hibernate developers confess that if you are updating a large dataset, its better to use a procedure rather than make multiple calls with hibernate over the network.

So to summarize I suggest to use procedures and functions for good performance

Answer (score 2):

The best option is *you'll figure it out*.  Sometimes using any ORM is perfectly fine and will support you, other instances it isn't the best option.  I think the real answer is it depends on what you're doing, how you're doing it and the quality of product design.  All of those make a difference and can greatly dictate a failure or success.

Bottom line, absolutes are a horrible policy -- Use the tech that works and fixes a problem.  If it starts being a problem, re-evaluate.